# Inverse of $A^T B A$ in terms of $(A^T A)^{-1}$. Positive definite $B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices

I'm not sure if this question has an answer but here it is. All matrices are real-valued.

I have a rectangular matrix $A$, and a positive-definite square matrix $B$.

I have a closed-form solution to the operator $O = (A^T A)^{-1}$.

Without further assumptions, is it possible to express $(A^T B A)^{-1}$ in terms of matrices $\{O,A,A^T,\sqrt B,\sqrt{B}^T,\sqrt{B}^{-1},\sqrt{B}^{-T}\}$? (A positive-definite square matrix has a unique square root, assume we are able to compute this and its inverse without too much trouble; $B$ may be diagonal).

I know there will be numerical procedures. I'm looking for a closed form expression that can be computed directly using the above list of matrices. Maybe it isn't possible.

Edit: if it isn't possible, what if we add $\{\sqrt O, O^{-1}, \sqrt O ^{-1}\}$?

Comment: I fixed the typo in your title. I hope you don't mind!

Comment: Thanks @CameronWilliams!

Comment: It is notable perhaps that (in the case where $A^TA$ is invertible)
$$
(A^TA)^{-1/2}[A^TBA](A^TA)^{-1/2}
$$
is a [compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_(functional_analysis)) of the matrix $B$, i.e. a submatrix of $B$ under a suitable change of basis. Unfortunately, this does not lead to any computational insight as far as I can tell

Comment: @BenGrossmann I have no idea what to do with that information, but thank you for the insight.

Comment: @Myridium As I said, I don't have any idea either. One interesting consequence, though, is that the eigenvalues of $(A^TA)^{-1/2}[A^TBA](A^TA)^{-1/2}$, which are equal to the eigenvalues of $(A^TA)^{-1}[A^TBA]$, will necessarily [interlace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem) the eigenvalues of $B$.

Comment: @Myridium Perhaps something to be taken away from my first comment is that if it's possible to solve your problem, then it should generally be possible to find the inverse of a submatrix of a matrix $M$ using $M^{-1}$. However, even this simple problem is not striaghtforward. That said, I suspect that something could be done for this simple "version of the problem" using the Woodbury formula